# Is copy and paste user-friendly in Mac?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, usability-testing, user-research

Whenever I use copy and paste files in Mac, my eyes always search for copy and paste text in Mac context menu when compared with windows context menu. Is copy and paste in Mac context menu user-friendly?

[image]  [image]

Comment: Pradeep, do the edits better reflect your question?

Comment: Anything wrong with using ⌘+c and ⌘+v ?

Comment: How does Windows do it?

Comment: @unor It doesn't show the name of what's being copied.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is user friendly. The OS is the context, so there is no duty to follow the convention established by another OS. The absence of consistent use of conventions between products is not evidence that one or the other is the right convention. It would be better to ask if `Copy "x"` is clearly informing the user of the action they are performing. I would argue yes, `Copy` is a fine word to represent duplication.

Answer (score 3):

Are you new to using Macs? If so, you are expecting different menu arrangements and your rote memory is "upset".

You might very well have asked the same question of PC "Copy and Paste" patterns  if you just started using PCs for the first time after being used to the Mac pattern.

If so, once you get used to the Mac, you can probably answer the question for yourself **IF Mac "Copy and Paste" offers as much or more convenience to you than the PC.** If you find you can't get used to it, then maybe it is less user friendly.

This is your personal experience. A more empirical answer is difficult to quantify. It would take a good bit of side-by-side comparison. I think the menu arrangement is a small part. Other things to consider are keyboard shortcuts, format capture and pasting options, context menu options, text copying, file copying and so on.

I find the Mac "Copy/Paste" experience more limited. I often find myself wishing I could copy a document while in the middle of opening or saving another. I prefer the Windows experience for this feature alone.

I suggest you see how quickly you get used to the pattern and examine which one serves you better while you accomplish your tasks. You will get your answer that way.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly you are asking if the way that MAC presents copy+paste is as friendly as the way Windows presents it. If you are ignoring the fact that both MAC and windows have the ctrl+c / ctrl+v and ⌘+c / ⌘+v options and simply looking only at the menu way of doing it then I would say they are about in user experience. They both have simple right click functions to bring up a menu and from there simply click copy or paste. **They both take the same amount of clicks to perform and serve the same functionality pretty flawlessly.** As I am not a MAC user I am simply going off of the images that you posted above and comparing them with the windows options. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am relatively new to the mac ( switched from a windows system ). At first it is a bit tedious as you would be new to the keys and the right click menu but considering everything it is the same as windows. Ctrl + c in win and cmd + c in mac . The right menu also takes the same amount of clicks to achieve the required task. It is just getting used to the OS . The mac is user friendly :)